# Pin model to world after tracking marker

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, windows-mixed-reality

I am developing an app with mixed reality glasses. In this application I have an animated 3D model and need to track the marker, the model is fixed (locked) where the marker was tracked, because after tracking, I need to remove the marker but the model has to remain where it was fixed.

I was only able to do the normal tracking with ImageTarget, where the 3D model is fixed on the marker and not on the world, and when removing the marker the 3d model disappears.

Another thing is that I need the animation of the 3D model to start only after it is fixed at the marker location.

Comment: What defines the point in time when the model gets pinned? What differentiates "moving the tracker around so the model shows up *here*" and "moving the tracker around, *because it isn't needed any more*"?

Comment: Hi Draco 18s,I want to use the tracker just to set the exact position where the model should be, after tracking (set the position) I want the model to be fixed at this point in relation to the world and stop following the marker.

Comment: That didn't answer my question. If the app is already running and you pick up a piece of paper with the tracker on it and flip it over, at what point is the tracker "in the exact position"?

Comment: My situation is as follows: My marker appears on a TV that is on a table with the screen facing upwards (it is a presentation support for an event). The marker appears on the TV screen only to position the 3D model on top of the tracker (so that the model is exactly on screen), so the model must be fixed in space; After you start playing a video on TV, the animation of the augmented reality 3D model will accompany the video playback at the same time, but independently, it will appear to be tracking but only playing at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

"I need to remove the marker but the model has to remain where it was fixed."

[vuforia should have an event that's something like "on marker lost tracking" or "on marker disappeared".](https://library.vuforia.com/content/vuforia-library/en/reference/unity/classVuforia_1_1DefaultTrackableEventHandler.html)

add a handler to that event, which will unparent your model from the marker, position it to the last known position of that marker, and starts the animation.

Comment: I want to know how I do it. I want that as soon as the marker is tracked the model will be fixed at that point in relation to the space and from that moment disable the marker. So when the marker is tracked and the model position is set over the marker, I can remove the marker and the model will continue at that point regardless of my movement.

Comment: @JONATASSILVA https://library.vuforia.com/content/vuforia-library/en/reference/unity/classVuforia_1_1DefaultTrackableEventHandler.html <-- add a handler in your code to this event, and in it, use the marker's position to put your model in that position.